# How to set IntelliJ to stop setting application priority to background?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-14

IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio keeps setting itself to background priority, takes ages to do anything, and I need to keep manually setting the priority to high.

How to stop this unnecessary, unhelpful and unwanted behaviour?

Comment: What OS do you use and how do you check the priority? On Windows it's set to Normal.

Comment: Win 10. Using Process Explorer. When starting up, choose another application and do stuff (like how a productive person would). Upon returning, would see that the application is super slow and unresponsive. Check Process Explorer again, and it would show "background".